# New to Django, mod_wsgi won't install

Tags: django, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

Currently using Django 2.2.3 and apache 2.4.10. When running 'pip install mod_wsgi' in my virtualenv it errors out with:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe'
failed with exit status 1120
```

I saw this https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/245 but I am already using virtualenv.

Any tips or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

I was trying to avoid updating XAMPP as it would require a ton of updates/changes to the rest of the database, but in the end I couldn't get anything else to work and so we updated XAMPP and now mod_wsgi installs fine.